Java access fields (variables) of a method
I need a way to get the variables of a method which called another method:
public void testMethod(Event event) {
    restart();
}

public void restart() {
    //somehow get the event-Variable of the testMethod 
    //**WITHOUT** passing it into the method.
}

I already tried to go over the StackTrace:
private void logCaller() {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    if (stackTrace.length > 2) {
        StackTraceElement caller = stackTrace[2];
        System.out.println("Method called from: " + caller.getClassName() + "." + caller.getMethodName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Method called from unknown source.");
    }
}

But I didnt get it to correctly give me the event variable used in the method which called restart()
And if I remember correctly the fields only give the set variables in the class, not the arguments of a method.

You can't, is the short answer.  (A good thing, too.)

Not entirely impossible, the debug API allows debugging yourself but with lots of catches and not recommended for production code at all. More to serve curiosity.
